# aggridOptions.api.addItems sets data upside down

Tags: ag-grid

I am using aggridOptions.api.addItems to add array of data to my grid. the function adds my data from the end to the start.

if my array is [1,2,3,4,5] I see it in my grid after the insert as [5,4,3,2,1]. How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in the implementation - we've fixed it and it'll be available in the next scheduled release (to be released tomorrow).

You can either wait for the next release or manually insert the items one by one.

Given the fix will be released tomorrow however I'd just wait for it and this issue will go away for you.

Comment: Sure - I'll post here once the release has been done. Are you on the Members Forum too? If so I'll post there instead - let me know

Comment: Yes, I am a Forum member too. I you can please post here. Thanks

Comment: Sure, thats fine - will do

Comment: Maybe you can help me with one more issue. I am trying to build filter that will be located inside the header as a input field right under the header title(the way ui-grid is doing). Is there an example that someone did filters like that?

Comment: Hi - no, this is unfortunately not currently possible. Its on the list of items we want to do, but is not yet scheduled for inclusion

Comment: hi - the release how now been done that fixes this issue